# urlencode internet explorer problem

Tags: php, browser, encoding, internet-explorer-8

I am having a strange problem with Internet Explorer and greek encoded get variables. I have a simple script (utf-8 encoded) in php that does the following:

```
$term = $_GET['term'];
// term processing
echo htmlspecialchars($term);
echo '<form method="GET" action="/script.php">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="ref" value="'.$term.'">';
echo '<input type='submit' value="do submit()">';
echo '</form>';
```

I call the script the usual way: http://localhost/form.php?term=διαστημοπλοιο.
Now while in chrome, firefox (mac), safari (mac) the value gets ok (it will display %CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BF - percent utf-8 encoded), in Internet Explorer 8+ (windows) I get garbled text (empty squares). Is there something I should check? I used mb_detect_encoding and the string is UTF-8 encoded.

I've also used the following tests (php code below) and there are differences between browsers:

```
header("Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8");
$term = $_GET['term'];
echo "<pre>";
echo "DECODED:".urldecode($term)."\n";
echo "TERM ENCODING (FROM BROWSER) [mb_detect_encoding]:".mb_detect_encoding($term)."\n";
echo "UTF-8:\n";
echo 'URLDECODE:'."\t".urlencode($term)."\n";
echo 'RAWURLDECODE:'."\t".rawurlencode($term)."\n";
echo 'URLDECODE:'."\t".urldecode(utf8_encode(urlencode($term)))."\n";
echo 'RAWURLDECODE:'."\t".rawurlencode($term)."\n";
echo "UTF-8->cp1253 iv:\n";
$zz = iconv('UTF-8','cp1253',$term);
echo 'URLDECODE:'."\t".urlencode(iconv('UTF-8','cp1253',$term))."\n";
echo "cp1253->UTF-8 iv:\n";
echo 'URLDECODE:'."\t".urlencode(iconv('cp1253','UTF-8',$zz))."\n";
echo "</pre>";
```

The results on mac/linux were:

```
DECODED:διαστημοπλοιο
TERM ENCODING (FROM BROWSER) [mb_detect_encoding]:UTF-8
UTF-8:
URLDECODE:  %CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BF
RAWURLDECODE:   %CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BF
URLDECODE:  διαστημοπλοιο
RAWURLDECODE:   %CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BF
UTF-8->cp1253 iv:
URLDECODE:  %E4%E9%E1%F3%F4%E7%EC%EF%F0%EB%EF%E9%EF
cp1253->UTF-8 iv:
URLDECODE:  %CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BF
```

The results on IE were:

```
DECODED:�������������
TERM ENCODING (FROM BROWSER) [mb_detect_encoding]:UTF-8
UTF-8:
URLDECODE:  %E4%E9%E1%F3%F4%E7%EC%EF%F0%EB%EF%E9%EF
RAWURLDECODE:   %E4%E9%E1%F3%F4%E7%EC%EF%F0%EB%EF%E9%EF
URLDECODE:  �������������
RAWURLDECODE:   %E4%E9%E1%F3%F4%E7%EC%EF%F0%EB%EF%E9%EF
UTF-8->cp1253 iv:

Notice:  iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string in /Users/xalapan/Sites/drupal/io.php on line 15

Notice:  iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string in /Users/xalapan/Sites/drupal/io.php on line 16
URLDECODE:  
cp1253->UTF-8 iv:
URLDECODE:
```

Comment: So, apparently when you are dealing with Greek Characters a workaround is to use the following:

    $term = $_GET['term'];
    $term = iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-7',$term); // because we deal with greek characters.

When it is sent as a QUERY_STRING (that's what the form does ultimately) the browsers (all browsers, all OSes) reconvert it again to UTF-8 for a strange reason.

Comment: [This article](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding) (link from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17267061/177710)) explains very well that different parts of your URL need to be decoded (encoded) independently. So this might (have) be(en) part of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `htmlspecialchars()`, not `urlencode()`. Not using htmlspecialchars leads to XSS vulnerabilities.

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="ref" value="'.htmlspecialchars($term).'">';
```

Also, the values in `$_GET` are *already* decoded. You must not decode them again.

Comment: I am updating the code in my answer. But the garbled text still exists even with htmlspecialchars. Is there something to do with developer tools on IE? Quirks / IE7 / IE8 changes the way of encoding?